# Weird FIOS router issue started TODAY and b0rked Windows PCs only

Tags: wireless-networking, router, fios

So this morning when I woke up, I experienced something I've never seen.

All of my windows PCs (4 of them) could get on my Wifi, but not access the internet.  All internet addresses would ping to 1.1.1.1.

My 2 android devices worked fine.

I spent a bunch of time trying to find the root cause, including a clear reinstall on 1 pc.

What fixed it, amazingly, is restoring my Verizon provided wifi router to factory settings.  All my devices work if on factory settings.  If I change anything in my router settings, the Windows PCs only break.  Change SSID == break.  Change password == break.  Change security model == break.

Any idea why this is happening?  Should I get a new Wifi router?
I'd prefer I well customized router, but I also need it to work for work!

Comment: For the fun of it, can you change your DNS server to 8.8.8.8? Go to the network configuration in the control panel, click on change adapter settings, right click on the adapter that shows as active, single click on TCP/IP v4 settings, and click on configure. Then you manually enter 8.8.8.8 and see if you can visit a page.

Comment: Check to see if the router firmware was updated recently (verizon pushes them out occasionally), if it has a recent date roll back the firmware.